# redirect_uri_mismatch: http://localhost:4500/AUTH/auth/google/callback, does not match t

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, passport.js, google-api-nodejs-client

there are tons of questions with this issue, I read them all but did not see any similar issue. in my case "auth" is prepending. this is what i registered in the app settings as call back url

http://localhost:4500/auth/google/callback

this is passport.js configuration:

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy.Strategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,// "!" is typescript 
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      callbackURL: "auth/google/callback",
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
      if (existingUser) {
        done(undefined, existingUser);
      }
      const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
      done(undefined, user);
    }
  )
);
```

Here are the routes:

```
export const authRoutes = (app: Application) => {
  //with passing "google" passport knows that it will use GoogleStrategy
  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
  );

  app.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate("google"));
  app.get("/auth/current_user", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
  app.get("/auth/logout", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    req.logout();
    res.json({ user: req.user });
  });
};
```

here is the error message:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:4500/auth/auth/google/callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/$%7Byour_client_id%7D?project=$%7Byour_project_number%7D)

Comment: Can you add the whole error message ? ( Title only has a half of the error msg which is not useful )

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no exclamation mark. I did not set the callback url as env. only db, client id and client secret

Comment: "http://localhost:4500/auth/auth/google/callback" Why this one has 2 `auth` parts ?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone this is typescript. sorry I should have mentioned that. I ll update the question

Comment: @Dilshan that is the issue. I dont understant wh google is returning "/auth/auth/google/callback"

Comment: Can you try to replace the `callbackURL` with the full URL just for test weather it works or not ?

Comment: Or replace , `callBackUrl : "auth/google/callback"` to `callBackUrl : "/auth/google/callback"`

Comment: @Dilshan  adding "/" is not working and full url is not working neither

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google developer console. Make sure you are checking the correct project and the correct client.  This needs to be the one you are using in your code.  Then add

```
http://localhost:4500/auth/auth/google/callback
```

As a redirect URI.

If google says its not set its not set, you need to double check remember the port matters as well as the protocol, even a trailing / would make it a miss match.

Comment: DalmTo, thank you for your response. I dont understand why and how I am getting this url "http://localhost:4500/auth/auth/google/callback"

Comment: You are using the Google apis node js client library this is the redirect uri it is designed to use.